# Vim: Del in Insert Mode

Tags: vim

Is there any key combination that simulate the Del in Vim insert mode? For the Backspace, there is the Ctrl-H which is very convenient, and make it easier than pushing the far away Backspace button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html There are a few more built-in key combinations for various tasks.

Also you can set your own mappings using .vimrc for example your given example is just

```
imap ^H <Left><Del>
```

Answer (score 5):

On my vim installation, <kbd>Del</kbd> in insert mode Just Works. `:help i_<Del>`

If <kbd>Del</kbd> isn't doing what you want, you can try `:fixdel`.  `:help :fixdel` has a good explanation of what that tries to fix.

If you simply wanted to simulate <kbd>Del</kbd> via another Ctrl-key mapping (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>), I'd recommend the following mapping:

```
imap <C-D> <C-O>x
```

<kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> in insert mode will allow you to run a single normal mode command and automatically return back to insert mode.  `x` deletes the key under the cursor.

Comment: Yes, Del works with with my installation also, but I wanted something easier than having to remove your right hand from its best location on the middle row, press <Del>, and then return back your hand :-)

Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: imap <C-d> <Del> is a nice alternative.

Comment: `Ctrl`+`O` and a single normal mode command - is a good 'workaround'!

Answer (score 2):

You can map keys yourself in vim, including insert mode. The following article reveals more details:
[Mapping keys in VIM](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1))